# In firefox, how can filter bookmarks with non-empty keywords?

Tags: firefox

In firefox, i can assign quick search shortcuts (keywords) to the search engines in the small search toolbar item (e.g. 'g' for google, 'w' for wikipedia, etc)

I also can assign shortcuts to virtually any "search" field in any page, and firefox stores then as regular bookmarks (afaik), and then i simply assign keywords to each. Aside of 'search field' bookmarks, i can also assign keywords to any regular bookmark in firefox.

What i want is to get ONLY those bookmarks, the ones with keywords (so i can back them up aside regular bookmarks and use them elsewhere).

Is there a way to "list" or find all of those quick shortcuts / keywords i have? specially because some of them are scattered among several bookmark folders, and i don't want to look for them manually.

in other words, I'd like a way to filter the bookmarks and only get the ones with a non empty keyword. Is there a way of filtering that?

And, about the "regular" search engines and they keywords (the ones in the regular search toolbar item), where does firefox store them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `Bookmarks menu /Show All Bookmarks` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), then right-click the column headers and add the **Keyword** column as shown below:

[image: FF Keywords]

Then you can click that column header to sort by it and that should group all bookmarks/favorites with and without keywords separately.

As far as the OpenSearch plugin XMLs and associated icons go, they can be found in the `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<Profile_Name>\searchplugins` folder (see [this page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) for more).

Comment: ohh! that was so easy! i don't know why i never looked into the extra columns in the "all bookmarks" view. That is _EXACTLY_ what i needed! thank you very much. And thanks too for the info on the XMLs =)

Comment: Glad I could help! :)